# Is there a term for sets of words that have the same sense relation between them?

Tags: terminology, lexical-semantics

Sense relations are apparently semantic relationships between words and/or predicates.  We learn more about this at Glottopedia.org.

"A sense relation is a paradigmatic relation between words or predicates. 
Two major types of sense relations can be distinguished:

Sense relations of inclusion, esp. hyponymy and synonymy

Sense relations of exclusion, esp. complementarity and antonymy 
(both of which are instances of the relationship of incompatibility)."

Is there a term for sets of words that have the same sense relation between them?  For instance, how would one complete this paragraph?

"'up' and 'down' are antonyms.   'animal' is a hypernym of 'cow'   'pal' is a synonym of 'friend.'   Each pair of words just mentioned is a set of (term I'm looking for)."

Comment: Words that are synonyms are sometimes said to belong to the same **synset**. Is that the kind of term you're looking for?

Comment: @robert This was my first thought as well, but do you know if the word "synset" predates [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it could have come up together with WordNet.

Comment: I'm after the hypernym of "synonym, antonym, hyponym, hypernym" and any other term that stands for words that stand for certain sense relation that exist among sets of words.  Note the definition above, which I found at this link:  http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Sense_relation